# BIRT: Multiple Actions on Mouse-over in pie chart

Tags: charts, tooltip, birt, pie-chart, onmouseover

I want to execute multiple actions (Highlight and Show tooltip) on mouse-over on a BIRT Pie chart.

```
Trigger t = TriggerImpl.create(TriggerCondition.ONMOUSEOVER_LITERAL,
        ActionImpl.create(ActionType.HIGHLIGHT_LITERAL, SeriesValueImpl.create(String.valueOf(sePie.getSeriesIdentifier()))));
  t.setTriggerFlow(TriggerFlow.CAPTURE_LITERAL);
  sePie.getTriggers().add(t);

  Trigger t1 = TriggerImpl.create(TriggerCondition.ONMOUSEOVER_LITERAL,
        ActionImpl.create(ActionType.SHOW_TOOLTIP_LITERAL, TooltipValueImpl.create(0, null)));
  t1.setTriggerFlow(TriggerFlow.CAPTURE_LITERAL);
  sePie.getTriggers().add(t1);
```

The problem is that only the latter action is put into effect on the chart. In the above code-block , when I mouse-over I see only the tooltip but the pie section is not highlighted. If I place the HIGHLIGHT block below the tooltip block, then pie is highlighted but I do not see the tooltip.

Please suggest how I can get both actions to take effect on mouse-over simultaneously.  Thanks in advance.